# Python can't UPDATE the time between 2 times to mySQL

Tags: php, python, mysql, python-3.x

I have table with 3 column: `ID; TIMEON; TIMEOFF; TIMES` with data

> 22 | 2016-05-25 19:17:11 | 2016-05-26 18:26:43 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import MySQLdb
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from time import localtime, strftime, strptime

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="123", passwd="tesst", db="raspi")
cur= db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT TIMEON, TIMEOFF FROM DP WHERE Id = 22")
time_results = cur.fetchall()
for row in time_results:
    tgianON = row[0]
    tgianOFF = row[1]
aaa = abs(tgianOFF - tgianON)
print aaa
cur.execute("UPDATE DP SET TIMEUSE=%s WHERE Id = %s",(aaa, 22))
db.commit()
cur.close()
db.close()
```

- I want to caculate time between `TIMEON` and `TIMEOFF` then insert it to mysql in current row (`TIMES` in my table) but run it error:
- It can print the time but can't insert data

> 22:46:54
>
> tet.py:17: Warning: Out of range value for column 'TIMEUSE' at row 1
>         cur.execute("UPDATE DP SET TIMEUSE=%s WHERE Id = %s",(aaa, 22))

I think it wrong for the format of `aaa`. Is it correct ?

Comment: The most important thing here is that you shouldn't be doing this at all. The result of simple calculations should not be saved in the database.

Comment: The second thing here is that you are actually trying to set a TIMEUSE column while your column (according to you) is named TIMEOFF

Comment: Can you please share the desc of table? That is desc DP;